# JavaMe deploy

Tags: eclipse, deployment, java-me, lwuit

Im using Eclipse 3.4, EclipseMe 1.7.9. Im trying to deploy/"create package" a simple project with an external .jar file ([LWUIT.jar](https://lwuit.dev.java.net/)) included. When I try to create the package with the the .jar file exported (Properties -> Java build path -> order and export)
I receieve the following error msg: "Error during build"

(Details: Errors during build.
  Errors running builder 'Preverification' on project 'Try'.
  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.getTarget(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
  org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModel.getTarget(Lorg/eclipse/core/resources/IContainer;Lorg/eclipse/core/runtime/IPath;Z)Ljava/lang/Object;
)

How to make the build succeed?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems to be a [known issue on Eclipse 3.4](http://www.mail-archive.com/eclipseme-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg01254.html).

At the time of the thread mentionned above (July 2008), adding the url http://eclipseme.org/testversions to the software updates list, and upgraded to eclipseMe 1.8 did solve the issue.

Could you check if you can upgrade eclipseMe and still reproduce the problem ?

Comment: Thanks, it solved the problem. Weird that I had to manually install the 1.8. Eclipse update only found 1.7.9

Comment: +1 You are the man VonC.